# MapStruct Map Object to List

Tags: java, mapstruct

I am trying to use Mapstruct to map source object to a target list. What should be a clean mapstruct way of doing this?

Below are my DTO's.

Source DTO

```
@Data
class Source
{

String a;

String b;

String C;

}
```

Target DTO

```
@Data
class Target
{

String name;

List<Child> customList;

}

@Data
class Child
{

String attr1;

boolean attr2;

}
```

I am facing issues with Mapper Class. Trying to achieve something like below.

```
public interface CustomMapper
{

@Mapper(target="customList" expression="java(new Child(a,false))"
@Mapper(target="customList"  expression="java(new Child(b,true))"
@Mapper(target="customList"  expression="java(new Child(c,false))"
Target sourceToTarget(Source source);


}
```

I don't want to use qualifiedBy function like below to achieve this, as all conversion needs to be coded for each element.

```
List<Child> toList(Source source)
{
   List<Child> customList = new ArrayList<Child>();
   customList.add(new Child(source.getA(),false));
   customList.add(new Child(source.getB(),true)); 
   customList.add(new Child(source.getC(),false));

    return customList;
}
```

Comment: Do, IIUC, the list will always 3 elements (child)?

Comment: @Sjaak No, your list can have any number of elements. In the above example depends on source DTO

Comment: What I meant is: does the number of elements depend on the number of properties in class source? So now you have three elements corresponding to a,b,c. But suppose you have d as well.. would your list contain 4 elements? That's what I got from your example

Comment: Correct, it depends on number of properties in class source.

Comment: Stuck at same issue! you got your problem resolved through the annotation way? any trace (And are you the same guy from Y****ks)

Answer (score 9):

I have used an expression to solve this problem. The expression is to perform the mapping (for objects, straightforward for Strings), and then convert it to a list.

```
  @Mapping(target = "names", expression = "java(Arrays.asList(map(source.getName())))")
  TargetObject map(SourceObject source);
  
  TargetName map(SourceName source)
```

You need to import "Arrays" class in the @Mapper definition as below.

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE, componentModel = "spring", imports = {Arrays.class})
```

Answer (score 5):

I had similar use case where i want to convert and `Single Object` to `List` of objects.
As these are very custom requirements, will be hard for `mapstruct` to provide some API for use cases like this.

I ended up implementing using `default method` like this

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
interface MyMapper {
    
    default List<SomeObject> from(SourceObject sourceObject) {
      //Add Mappig logic here 
      //return the list

    }
 }
```

//If you want to use some mapper for mapping

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class SomeArrayMapper {

    @Autowired
    SomeMapper mapper;

    public SomeUser[] from(SingleObject singleObject) {
         SomeUsers[] Users = new SomeUser[1];
         
        Users[0] =  mapper.toUser(singleObject);;
        return Users ;
    }
}
```

In some cases **Decorators** can also be useful take a look at [here](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#customizing-mappers-using-decorators)

Answer (score 2):

There is no clean way of doing this at the moment in MapStruct. MapStruct is considerring bean tot map mapping. See here: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/pull/1744 which might come in helpful once implemented.

However, if you really have a lot of properties and this is a recurring problem, and you dislike reflection - like I do - you might want to give code generation an attempt and DIY. I posted an example some while ago for generating a mapper repository here: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-mapper-repo but, it's a bit of an steep learning curve.. sorry

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/pull/1744 has been merged